# Editing the 'default front page' base URL

Tags: 7, uri

I rebuilt a new server from another server's image. And I want to use it for a new domain, but I'm finding that the new server continues to redirect to the original server's domain.

Going to the new server's drupal admin console, I see that the domain (ie, https://mysite.com/) is uneditable under Configuration > System > Site Information > Front Page > Default Front Page.

I tried setting the 'base_url' in /etc/drupal/7/sites/default/settings.php to my new domain and flushed the cache, but that didn't resolve the problem (and the old domain still persists in the console).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the below changes in your settings.php and .htaccess?

```
 /sites/default/settings.php

$base_url = 'http://www.example.com'; // NO trailing slash!
```

and

```
.htaccess

  # Modify the RewriteBase if you are using Drupal in a subdirectory and
  # RewriteBase /drupal
```

Try using this.

Answer (score 0):

Have a closer look at settings.php the value may be hardcoded there

In particular: `$conf['site_frontpage']` or `$base_url`

You may also just need to flush all caches at Admin > Config > Performance

Comment: the $base_url is set to the new domain and setting $conf['site_frontpage'] and flushing the cache didn't resolve the issue. any other suggestions?

Comment: It sounds like something else might be hardcoding the `$base_url` value. Have a grep/find-in-files search for  `base_url` in your site module / theme files

Comment: did a grep on the module and didn't find anything that would be pointing to the old domain =(

Answer (score 0):

This could be set in a lot of places.

You should try searching all your code for mention of the previous domain and go from there.

```
grep -irn "example.com" .
```

Where `example.com` is the old domain.

This will list all matches of `example.com`. At the beginning you'll see the files. Then the line numbers. Then the string that it matched.